# Http inbound gateway failing Illegal charset

Tags: spring, http, character-encoding, gateway, inbound

I am trying to write an integration test over a service created using Http inbound gateway  and it is giving me the error "java.nio.charset.UnsupportedCharsetException: cesu-8". Any idea why? This service is working correctly. We have a package app that uses it multiple times a day. I would like to have an integration test that can call it as well. Here is my test:

```
@Test
public void receiveMessage() throws IOException {
    final String xml = testUtil.getTestDocumentAsString("/serviceTestData/document.xml");

    final RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();
    template.getMessageConverters()
            .add(0, new StringHttpMessageConverter(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
    final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    MediaType mediaType = new MediaType("text", "xml", StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    headers.setContentType(mediaType);

    final String credentials = this.user + ":" + this.pass;
    final byte[] message = credentials.getBytes("UTF-8");
    headers.add("Authorization", "Basic " + DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(message));
    final HttpEntity request = new HttpEntity(xml, headers);
    final ResponseEntity<Ack> result = template.postForEntity(url, request, Ack.class);

    System.out.println(result.getBody().getStatus());
}
```

Error:
    Root cause of ServletException.
    java.nio.charset.UnsupportedCharsetException: cesu-8
        at java.nio.charset.Charset.forName(Charset.java:536)
        at org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders.getAcceptCharset(HttpHeaders.java:596)
        at org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper.getHttpHeader(DefaultHttpHeaderMapper.java:963)
        at org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper.toHeaders(DefaultHttpHeaderMapper.java:460)
        at org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper.toHeaders(DefaultHttpHeaderMapper.java:72)
        at org.springframework.integration.http.inbound.HttpRequestHandlingEndpointSupport.actualDoHandleRequest(HttpRequestHandlingEndpointSupport.java:459)
        at org.springframework.integration.http.inbound.HttpRequestHandlingEndpointSupport.doHandleRequest(HttpRequestHandlingEndpointSupport.java:399)
        at org.springframework.integration.http.inbound.HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway.handleRequest(HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway.java:103)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.handle(HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.java:51)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:751)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:844)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:280)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:254)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:136)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:341)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:215)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3388)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3354)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2238)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2154)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2132)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1564)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:254)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:312)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:264)

Answer (score 0):

I’m not familiar with Java or Spring, but:

> Error: Root cause of ServletException. java.nio.charset.UnsupportedCharsetException: cesu-8
>
> at java.nio.charset.Charset.forName(Charset.java:536)
>
> at org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders.getAcceptCharset(HttpHeaders.java:596)
>
> [...]
>
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)

This suggests that your test request contains an HTTP header like `Accept-Charset: cesu-8`, which your server fails to interpret.

It seems like your request is generated by the `RestTemplate` class. Check what it does with headers. Search for `Accept-Charset` (or `AcceptCharset`) and `cesu-8` in particular.